# How to differentiate virtualhosts in Apache's log files?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, virtualhost

I wanted to make a simple access statistic based on apache's access log, but I found out that I can't tell vhosts in the log file apart. I don't really want to make separate log files for each vhost, so what can I do? Is there a possibility of custom-formatting the log file's entries? I'd also prefer to make this change globally, without the need to update every virtualhost entry.

For example I get lines like this one (it's a Bing bot):

```
65.55.52.92 - - [07/Dec/2013:16:04:02 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 59
```

and I can't tell what website's robots.txt it was trying to access.

Comment: Changing every vhost file is as easy as `sed -i 's/CustomLog(.*)combined/CustomLog\1MyLogFormat/' *` (or something like that).  I'm sure there's a way of doing that with Powershell if you're on Windows.

Comment: @Ladadadada, I'd have to add the CustomLog directive for every VHost first and maintain it. Thankfully this directive can go to the body of httpd.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify a custom [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive along with a [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive to format the log messages in a manner that suits your needs. The documentation for [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) is really well written and easy to follow.

You probably want to add a `%v` to your LogFormat directive

> %v     The canonical ServerName of the server serving the request.

Comment: Thank you; There's actually exactly the directive I need in the apache doc: `"%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"`